# I Cant figure out how to do this in JAVA

Tags: java, list, class, methods, constants

I am doing a program that has different classes(APO1, Oganic, Lab, Calculus ) and each one belongs to a department (math, chemistry, etc). Now I have to create a method that counts how many classes are in a department, but i cant figure out how. I have 2 java classes called "Class" and "CertificateGrades".

- I created String constants

  ```
     public final static String MATH = "Math";
     public final static String CHEMISTRY = "Chemistry";
     public final static String PHYSICS = "Physics";
  ```
- I created a constructor method like this

  ```
   public Class( String pName, String pDepartment, int pNumberCredits )
      {
          pName = name ;
          pDepartment = nameDepartment ;
          pNumberCredits = numberCredits;
          grade = -1;
      }
  ```

-Created the classes as objects

```
public CertificateGrades( )
   {
    Class class1= new Class("APO1", Class.MATH, 3);
    Class class2= new Class("Calculus", Class.MATH, 3);
    Class class3= new Class("Organic", Class.CHEMISTRY, 3);
    Class class4= new Class("Lab", Class.PHYSICS, 1);
   }
```

-Finally I cant figure out how to make a method (thats what the teacher asked) that counts how many classes are in a department

```
public int giveNumberClassesDepartment( String pDepartment )
    {
        ????????????????????????

    }
```

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer these code. I used a simple way like a List
//Class

```
public class Class {
    public final static String MATH = "Math";
    public final static String CHEMISTRY = "Chemistry";
    public final static String PHYSICS = "Physics";

    private String pName;


    private String pDepartment;
    private int pNumberCredits;
    private double grade;

    public Class(String pName, String pDepartment, int pNumberCredits) {
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pDepartment = pDepartment;
        this.pNumberCredits = pNumberCredits;
        this.grade = -1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the pName
     */
    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    /**
     * @param pName the pName to set
     */
    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the pDepartment
     */
    public String getpDepartment() {
        return pDepartment;
    }

    /**
     * @param pDepartment the pDepartment to set
     */
    public void setpDepartment(String pDepartment) {
        this.pDepartment = pDepartment;
    }

    /**
     * @return the pNumberCredits
     */
    public int getpNumberCredits() {
        return pNumberCredits;
    }

    /**
     * @param pNumberCredits the pNumberCredits to set
     */
    public void setpNumberCredits(int pNumberCredits) {
        this.pNumberCredits = pNumberCredits;
    }

    /**
     * @return the grade
     */
    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    /**
     * @param grade the grade to set
     */
    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

//CertificateGrades

```
public class CertificateGrades {


    private List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

    public void addClass(Class clazz) {
        this.classes.add(clazz);
    }

    public CertificateGrades() {
        mockData();
    }

    /**
     * mock data
     * */
    public void mockData() {
        Class class1= new Class("APO1", Class.MATH, 3);
        Class class2= new Class("Calculus", Class.MATH, 3);
        Class class3= new Class("Organic", Class.CHEMISTRY, 3);
        Class class4= new Class("Lab", Class.PHYSICS, 1);
        classes.add(class1);
        classes.add(class2);
        classes.add(class3);
        classes.add(class4);
    }

    public int giveNumberClassesDepartment( String pDepartment )
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            if(clazz.getpDepartment().equals(pDepartment)) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very very odd way to do it.

The better solution is to create a class called `Math` which `extends Class`. Then, create a class called `Calculus` and `APO1`. With that, you can now make those two classes `extends Math`.

Do the same with the physics.

Now all you have to do is create an `ArrayList` that holds type Math, and add your classes of type `Calculus and APO1` into that `ArrayList`. (Calculus and APO1 both `extends Math`, remember?)

You can now create a method like so :

```
public int giveNumberClassesDepartment(ArrayList<Class> arrayList)
    {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
```

Now insert your `ArrayList` that holds type `Math` into that method, and it should correctly return the right number.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Henry98 is saying about creating an array list that holds your class values and then returning the .size of the array will tell you how many classes are in a department.

But the problem I have with your question is the way you're organizing your code and what you're actually asking for. Could you try to re-word your question to more accurately ask for what you need. And I think your code needs to be reworked from the bottom up.

Comment: Kennys answer was what I was going for, just jumped a step